# Proving $(\log_{2}n)^x \leq x^{x}n$ for $x>0$ and $n$ a natural number

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I've been trying to prove that
$$(\,\log_{2}n\,)^x \leq x^{x}n$$
for every $x>0$ and $n$ a natural number, for a while now and was wondering if there is something obvious that I'm missing? Because it shouldn't be that difficult but I'm really struggling.

Comment: Presumably, $n$ is a natural ?

Comment: Yes, n being a natural. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just takes some algebraic manipulation.

$$\log_2 n \leq (nx^x)^{1/x}$$
$$\log_2 n \leq (n^{1/x})x$$
$$(1/x)\log_2 n \leq n^{1/x}$$
$$\log_2 (n^{1/x}) \leq n^{1/x}$$
$$n^{1/x} \leq 2^{(n^{1/x})}$$

From here, one must  recognize that for any positive real number $g$...

$$g \leq 2^g$$

and that $n^{1/x}$ is a positive real number given your conditions for $x$ and $n$.

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take $n = 2^k$, then you need to show that
\begin{align}
k^x \le x^x 2^k\\
\iff  \frac{k}{x}  \le 2^{\frac{k}{x}}\\
\end{align}
It suffices to show that $2^t > t$ for $t >0$.

Consider $f(t) = 2^t -t$, then $f'(t) =  2^t \log(2) -1 $.

And $f''(t) = 2^t(\log(2))^2 > 0$. So $f$ is convex and $f$ has a global minimum at $t_0$ such that $f'(t_0) =0 \implies  2^{t_0} =1/\log(2) \implies f(t_0) =2^{t_0} -t_0 = \frac{1 +\log(\log(2))}{\log(2)} >0$.

So, $f(t) \ge f(t_0) > 0$. That is, $2^t>t$